Custom Auto Complete Using extension.js in GitHub Codespace
I am trying to build a custom auto complete for saving processes in GitHub using Mermaid Chart. The auto complete is essentially meant to be a data base of previously used names for nodes to help me follow a naming convention when documenting process in this system.
The issue that I am running into is that the auto complete that I have made logs all new node names as I am type them in, including the partial names.
enter image description here
When I remove the '' from the list completeEndChars the extension no longer works, but I'm fairly sure that this is what is causing the every sub option to be added. Any help would be appreciated.
#extension.js
const vscode = require('vscode');

// Store user-defined options and their usage counts
let userDefinedOptions = new Map();

function activate(context) {
    // Load previously saved options
    const savedOptions = vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().get('dynamicCompletion.options', []);
    userDefinedOptions = new Map(savedOptions.map(option => [option, 0])); // Initialize usage count

    // Register a completion item provider
    let provider = vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
        { scheme: 'file', language: 'markdown' }, // Targeting markdown for Mermaid charts
        {
            provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
                const linePrefix = document.lineAt(position).text.substr(0, position.character);
                if (!linePrefix.endsWith('.')) {
                    return undefined;
                }

                const currentInput = linePrefix.split('.').pop(); // Get the current word after the last dot

                // Sort completion items based on how closely they match the current input
                let completionItems = Array.from(userDefinedOptions.keys())
                    .filter(option => option.includes(currentInput)) // Show only full matches
                    .map(option => {
                        let item = new vscode.CompletionItem(option, vscode.CompletionItemKind.Text);
                        item.sortText = String(userDefinedOptions.get(option) || 0); // Sort by usage count
                        return item;
                    })
                    .sort((a, b) => a.sortText.localeCompare(b.sortText)); // Sort by usage

                return completionItems;
            },
            resolveCompletionItem(item) {
                return item;
            }
        },
        '.' // Trigger completion after typing "."
    );

    context.subscriptions.push(provider);

    // Register the Clear Memory Command
    let clearMemoryCommand = vscode.commands.registerCommand('dynamic-completion.clearMemory', () => {
        // Clear the in-memory options
        userDefinedOptions.clear();

        // Update the configuration to clear stored options
        vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('dynamicCompletion.options', [], true);

        // Notify the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Dynamic Completion memory has been cleared.');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(clearMemoryCommand);

    // Listen for changes to the document
    vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(event => {
        const editor = vscode.window.activeTextEditor;
        if (editor && event.document === editor.document) {
            const line = editor.document.lineAt(editor.selection.active.line).text.trim();
            const lastDotIndex = line.lastIndexOf('.');

            if (lastDotIndex !== -1) {
                const completedSection = line.substr(lastDotIndex + 1).trim();

                // Check if the completed section ends with one of the specified characters
                const nextCharIndex = lastDotIndex + completedSection.length + 1;
                const nextChar = line.charAt(nextCharIndex) || '';

                // Define characters that signify the end of a complete option
                const completeEndChars = ['[', '{', '(', ' ', '\n',''];

                // Check if the option ends with one of the specified characters
                if (completeEndChars.includes(nextChar)) {
                    const newCompletion = line.substring(0, nextCharIndex).trim();
                    if (newCompletion && !userDefinedOptions.has(newCompletion)) {
                        userDefinedOptions.set(newCompletion, 0); // Store the full line

                        // Store this information persistently
                        vscode.workspace.getConfiguration().update('dynamicCompletion.options', Array.from(userDefinedOptions), true);

                        // Notify the user about the new option
                        vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`New autocompletion option added: "${newCompletion}"`);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

function deactivate() {}

module.exports = {
    activate,
    deactivate
};


#package.json
{
  "name": "dynamic-completion",
  "displayName": "Dynamic Completion",
  "description": "An extension that learns from user input for autocompletion in Mermaid chart markdown",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.92.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [
    "onLanguage:markdown",
    "onCommand:dynamic-completion.clearMemory"
  ],
  "main": "./extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "dynamic-completion.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      },
      {
        "command": "dynamic-completion.clearMemory",
        "title": "Clear Autocompletion Memory"
      }
    ],
    "configuration": {
      "type": "object",
      "title": "Dynamic Completion",
      "properties": {
        "dynamicCompletion.options": {
          "type": "array",
          "description": "List of user-defined options for autocompletion in Mermaid charts",
          "default": []
        }
      }
    },
    "languages": [
      {
        "id": "markdown",
        "extensions": [".md"],
        "aliases": ["Markdown"]
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "pretest": "npm run lint",
    "test": "vscode-test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/vscode": "^1.92.0",
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.7",
    "@types/node": "20.x",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "typescript": "^5.4.5",
    "@vscode/test-cli": "^0.0.9",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.4.0"
  }
}

I tried removing the blank space "''" from completeEndChars, which seems to be what is causing the issue, but when it is removed the extension no longer works at all.
